# ImportError: No module named joy.msg

Tags: ros, rosaria, joystick, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do remote controll to my pioneer 2 robot, but when i run the launch file, i have this mistake "line 6, in  from joystick.msg import joy ImportError: No module named joy.msg" and I don't know how to solve that; I have the teleop_base, Rosaria and the app in the ipad.

thanks for all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12744/importerror:-no-module-named-joy.msg/) by [Kryuchcov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1690/kryuchcov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kryuchcov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1690/kryuchcov/) on 2012-01-25**:
that is the launch file pioneer-iphone.launch,, I put more information down,,, thanks

**Comment by [Kryuchcov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1690/kryuchcov/) on 2012-01-25**:

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-24**:
Pls update the question with the details for the launch file you are using and the complete error to get quick help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you're using electric (otherwise please update your question with the necessary information)?

Since electric, the "joy" msg is in [sensor_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sensor_msgs), so you need to change   `from joystick.msg import joy` into:

```
  from sensor_msgs.msg import joy
```

in the affected code.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kryuchcov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1690/kryuchcov/) on 2012-01-26**:
thaks for the help, it solve one mistake, unfortunately I have others that I explain in my answer, down the question, if you can and have time, your help will be good received,, thanks

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2014-03-27**:
For anyone using hydro joy ought to be capitalized:

from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy